# Porque no funciona el enrutamiento en esta app de Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, bootstrap, typescript

He creado una app en angular (con `ng new [nombre]`) [el lenguaje de programación usado es typeScript y mi idea es hacer angular + bootstrap como se puede apreciar en el código de debajo], la app se muestra bien y compila, el problema esta al querer acceder a alguna ruta.

La ruta a la que quiero acceder es http://localhost:4200/ventas, como dato por si sirve de algo, me he fijado que si pongo rutas que no existan como http://localhost:4200/ofjjrwb la consola del navegador se queja pero al poner el /ventas no se queja, así que entiendo que como mínimo el tema de las rutas esta decente.

Lo que espero con vuestras respuestas es o bien saber como solucionarlo o saber como decir al AppComponent que no es un standAlone (en caso de que no lo fuera podría usar proyectos antiguos y copiar los app.* para que si funcionase, pero Angular se empeña que es standAlone aunque ponga el `standAlone: false`).

AppModule.ts:

```
 import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { PantallaVentasComponent } from './pantalla-ventas/pantalla-ventas.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PantallaVentasComponent,
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PantallaVentasComponent } from './pantalla-ventas/pantalla-ventas.component';




const routes: Routes = [

  
  { path: 'ventas', component: PantallaVentasComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found', pathMatch: 'full' }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

main.ts:

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

  /*
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
  */
```

app.config:

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration()]
};
```

AppComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Web';
}
```

App.routes.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


import { PantallaVentasComponent } from './pantalla-ventas/pantalla-ventas.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'ventas', component: PantallaVentasComponent},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

pantallaVentas.html:

```
<div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="testing" (change)="changed()">
    <p>This should appear</p>
</div>
```

Aclaraciones: Al no saber muy bien lo que estaba haciendo he creado un appModule como en mis proyectos antiguos ya que no lo tenia creado al generar la App (lo mismo con el app-routing). Si considerais que falta algún código más no dudeis en pedirmelo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Estas usando Angular 17?

Comment: Si, en efecto estoy usando la versión 17.0.0. Adjunto lo que me devuelve el `npm -v` por si te sirve de algo:
`Angular CLI: 17.0.0
Node: 20.9.0
Package Manager: npm 10.1.0
OS: win32 x64

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.0.0
@angular-devkit/core            17.0.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.0
@angular/cli                    17.0.0
@angular/ssr                    17.0.0
@schematics/angular             17.0.0`

Comment: No he checado la actualización pero ahora es `standalone` por defecto, en teoría quitando eso del componente debería de funcionar o si quieres crear un proyecto nuevo solamente agrega `--standalone=false` cuando hagas `ng new`

Comment: has añadido el  `<router-outlet/>` en el template del `AppComponent` ?

Comment: @akotech Si de hecho el AppComponent.html solo contiene esa etiqueta

Comment: @René quitandolo del componente no he conseguido nada, pero al generar una nueva app con la opción que comentas si que me ha desparecido y me deja hacer las cosas como antes, muchas gracias! 
De todas formas dejaré la pregunta abierta ya que tu comentario no considero que sea la respuesta que espera alguien que busque esto en stackOverflow. Si tienes una opinión diferente al respecto comentalo.

Comment: Si es que Angular 17 apenas salió esta semana, todavía falta ver que tanto cambio y va a tardar algo de tiempo para que los desarrolladores empiecen a usarlo y se topen con estos cambios